# Laravel eloquent how to get relationships relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have Users table,Jobs table and JobStatus table. I get user jobs using relationship

```
return User::find($dto->getUserId())
            ->jobs()
```

This will return all user jobs as collection, not as relationship inside user model.
Now I need to get jobs statuses, but when I try this

```
User::find($dto->getUserId())
            ->jobs()
            ->statuses()
```

I get error `Call to undefined method`. I need to get statuses as collection so I can use where,sort by etc while getting them from db. Is there any way to do so?

I need to do something like this , but with statuses

```
return User::find($dto->getUserId())
            ->jobs()
            ->has('status')
            ->where('role','responsible')
            ->where('jobs.created_at','>=',Carbon::now()->subDays($dto->getPeriod())->toDateString())
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve the jobs by filtering on the statuses relationship, you can do it like this:

```php
$user->jobs()->whereHas('statuses', function ($query) {
    // Perform filter on the query for jobs->statuses
})->get();
```

For more information about querying relationship existence: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

---

If you want to retrieve the statuses instances, you can do it like this:

```php
$statuses = JobStatus::where('created_at', '>=', now())
    ->whereHas('jobs', function ($query) use ($user) {
        $query->whereUserId($user->id);
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: I won't loop through them. I need to filter them like jobs. I added example to question

Comment: @randomdude I see, I've updated my answer. It depends if you want to retrieve the jobs by filtering the statuses, or retrieve the statuses itself.

Comment: I need to retrieve statuses itself, preferably without user and jobs. Thanks for good answer

Comment: No problem! If you don't want to filter with jobs or users, you can simply do `JobStatus::where(...)->get();`

Answer (score 0):

Just use jobs without parenthesises to get the model itself :

```
User::find($dto->getUserId())
            ->jobs
            ->statuses;
```

Comment: If I do so, I get error `Property [statuses] does not exist on this collection instance`

Answer (score 0):

define your statuses() function first with the relations in your model with the jobs

like many to many or one to many relationship

```
public function statuses(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Job')->withTimestamps();
}
```